# Не работает поиск в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

При поиске вордпресс выкидывает вот что:

> Search Results for: ...

И больше ничего. Насколько я понял, не добавлен какой-то код и из-за этого не выводятся результаты поиска. Подскажите, какой код нужно вставить? И главное - куда?

Comment: Доброго времени суток.
Посмотрите здесь - [wp-config.ru](http://wp-config.ru/sozdanie-tem/urok-14-pole-poisk-i-kalendar/)

Comment: Файл search.php, посмотрите есть ли там код, если да какой.

Answer (score 0):

Ищите в директории вашей темы файл search.php - там суть проблемы. Скорее всего, в этом файле ошибка, или его нет. Доступ к этому файлу можно получить и из админки.